# How to create API for PHPmotion video cms site?

Tags: php, ios

I am working on PHPmotion video cms website. I want to create API to access the videos links and its info  for creating app for iPhone.
 How can I create API for PHPmotion website to stream its videos in iPhone app. What is the best way to create API for iPhone? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Json to fetch the video url from server and play its content in the shared appication.

Comment: hi, can you send any reference links to do this using jSON?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app            you can follow this tutorial to get the video urls from your server